# jQuery filter not returning data element, only entire object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to `filter()` a jQuery list from a `<select>` and return a `data` attribute if the text matches. The match works, but I don't get the string contained in the data attribute: I get the entire object

```
$("#company_select option").filter(function(){
    var d = $(this).data("company_system_name");
    if ($(this).text() === val ) { return  d; };
})
```

Why does this happen. How can I get the data attribute returned?

Comment: can you make a jsfiddle?

Comment: filter is just that, it will filter the list of object you have given it, not manipulate them

Comment: Don't you need the `change` event instead?

Comment: Filter will get you multiple elements, you want `data("company_system_name")` of the first on or all?

Comment: You are using [.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) in wrong way.

Comment: @Regent What would you suggest?

Comment: @thomas if you want to get only one `option` data attribute and text of different `option`s doesn't overlap, you can simply use `$("#company_select option:contains('" + val + "')").data("company_system_name");` Otherwise, there already are good answers for multiple `option`s and for precise `option` text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filter is used to reduce a set of matched elements based on the criteria you chose. To actually get data from them you need to do this:

```
var d = $("#company_select option").filter(function(){
    return $(this).text() == val;
}).data('company_system_name');
```

Comment: Really simple and smart. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you want:

```
var optData = $("#company_select option").filter(function(){
    return $(this).text() === val;
}).data("company_system_name");
```

Answer (score 1):

[`$.fn.filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)  method returns filtered jQuery collection. Depending on what you want you can then grab the first filtered element data or all data attributes as array:

```
var $options = $("#company_select option").filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() === val;
});

// Get the data of the first filtered option
var firstData = $options.data('company_system_name');

// Get an array of all data attributes
var allData = $options.map(function() {
    return $(this).data("company_system_name");
}).get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var val = "a"
    , _data = $.map($("#company_select option"), function(el, i) {
                  return $(el).text() === val 
                         ? $(el).data("company_system_name")
                         : null
              });
console.log(_data)
```

```js
var val = "a"
    , _data = $.map($("#company_select option"), function(el, i) {
    return $(el).text() === val 
      ? $(el).data("company_system_name")
      : null
})

console.log(_data)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="company_select">
    <option data-company_system_name="a">a</option>
    <option data-company_system_name="b">b</option>
    <option data-company_system_name="b">b</option>
</select>
```